# Recursion returning false when it should be true

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I'm in the process of making a word matching recursion, however I ran into a problem. I have an if statement that would return true if the statement is true. I have a system.print line to test to see if it actually ran correctly and it does. However when the method is suppose to return true, it returns false.
Sorry if I'm being unclear, I hope my code clears it up.

```
public class A10 {

    public static int counter = 3;

    public static boolean match(String x, String y) {
        // If the x string's letter at place 'counter' is the same as y string's letter at place counter.
        if ((counter) >= x.length()) {
            System.out.println("RUNNING THIS METHOD");
            return true;
        }

        if (x.charAt(counter) == y.charAt(counter)) {
            counter++;
            match(x, y);
        }

        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(match("asdfasdf", "asdfasdf"));
    }
}
```

When you run it, it will print "RUNNING THIS METHOD", but then it will return false, when it should return true... Can someone tell me what's causing this and how I would fix it?

Comment: Did you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When `match()` calls itself recursively, it disregards the return value.**

Thus the following:

```
       match(x, y);
```

should be

```
       return match(x, y);
```

I would also suggest that you turn `counter` into an argument, thereby getting rid of the `static` state:

```
public static boolean match(String x, String y) {
    return match_helper(x, y, 0);
}

private static boolean match_helper(String x, String y, int counter) {
    if (counter >= x.length()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (x.charAt(counter) == y.charAt(counter)) {
        return match_helper(x, y, counter + 1);
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(match("asdfasdf", "asdfasdf"));
}
```

Your current version of `match()` can't be used more than once since it inadvertently keeps state between calls. The proposed version above does not have this flaw.

Answer (score 2):

You should `return match(x, y);` within your second `if`. This is the main principle of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first instance of called function returns output. But only the instance with counter >= x.length() has side effect to display the text.